# SSIS package / SQL Server Agent job maximum execution time

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have 2 SSIS packages started by a single SQL Server Agent Job.
The first package took approximatively 2h30 and the second failed after 0:50.
Unfortunately, I don't know where or why it failed but I want to first check if there are some limitations regarding the maximum execution time allotted to an SSIS package or to a SQL Server Job.
Is there anything like that?

Comment: Rather than wondering if it was a time out, and then trying to find out if there's a limit, why not find out the actual reason for the failure? If the reason isn't a time out (which is likely) then you've just wasted your time. If your car stops working, you don't change the battery and replace all the spark plugs, and then start wondering what the problem was; you start working out the problem first and then make the needed fix. The same applies to here. Check the logs, find out the error, and then fix that. If you don't know how, then ask a question about that error.

Comment: Yes I know that @Larnu, but unfortunately the SSIS package is provided "out-of-the-box" by the third party editor and worked sometimes (when there are not too much data to process).
I checked the log and unfortunately the only error I got is "Package execution failed"... Based on that it is hard to go deeper.

Comment: I assume you're looking in SQL Agent? Look at the logs in SSISDB; they provide much more information.

Comment: @DavidGROSPELIER I second Larnu's comment. Do you have a copy of either the package or solution locally? If yes, try opening it in Visual Studio and running it locally. This will give you a better understanding of the design. You will also be able to identify potential bottlenecks that need to be addressed. If there is no problem with the package, then that will be a hint to swim upstream to other processes to see if they are causing the problem.